# Grails 3.x Upgrading Plugins

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

Following the reference docs to [to upgrade a Grails 2.x plugin to Grails 3.x](http://docs.grails.org/3.0.4/guide/upgrading.html#upgradingPlugins)
I was thrown off by **Step 2** *- Copy sources from the original Grails 2 plugin.*

**Specifically** `cp -rf ../quartz-2.x/QuartzGrailsPlugin.groovy src/main/groovy/grails/plugins/quartz`

Does this mean I am to create the directories for `grails/plugins/quartz` in `src/main/groovy/`as it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote [this plugin](https://github.com/domurtag/migrate-2-grails3) which automatically copies source files from a Grails 2 plugin/app to a Grails 3 plugin/app during an upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for this plugin - very simple to implement. The only caveat is that I had trouble running the migrate command until after I compiled my grails-2.x project after adding this plugin to my buildConfig. In your docs this step was skipped.